# Is zooming in/out same as changing resolution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I have a search bar made of 3 elements.

- First a to hold the selected values from drop down.
- Second a `<img>` element for clearing selection
- Third a `<button>` for user to toggle between dropdown.

My problem - When I zoom beyond 100%, the img and button elements go a little bigger and the search bar looks haywire.

My questions -

1. How to make all three look like one element even if we zoom?
2. Is zooming in/out same as changing resolution?

If yes, then I can probably make use of media queries to fix the problem.

Comment: Share your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

zoom is some kind like responsive

add this to the header to prevent zoom on mobile so your website will looks like an app .

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```